# How to index and search two different tables which are in same datasource using single solr instance Or Solr Template fields not working properly

Tags: xml, solr, indexing, dataimporthandler, data-import

I want to index and search two different entity.

File name: **db-data-config.xml**

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="myindex" driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver://test-pc:1433;DatabaseName=SampleDB" user="username" password="password" />
    <document>


     <entity name="Employees" query="select * from employee" transformer="TemplateTransformer" dataSource="myindex">
            <field column="id" name="singlekey" />
            <field column="eId" name="eid" />
            <field column="eName" name="ename" />
            <field column="entity" template="Employee" name="entity" />
    </entity>

    <entity name="Products" query="select * from products" transformer="TemplateTransformer" dataSource="myindex">
            <field column="id" name="singlekey" />
            <field column="pId" name="pid" />
            <field column="pName" name="pname" />
            <field column="entity" template="Product" name="entity" />
    </entity>

</document>
```

File name: **schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="db" version="1.1">
  <types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
 </types>
 <fields>

    <!-- Employee -->
    <field name="eid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
    <field name="ename" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 

    <!-- Products -->
    <field name="pid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="pname" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />

    <!--Common fields-->
    <field name="entity" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="singlekey" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
</fields>
<uniqueKey>singlekey</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

**As per below link:**
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636209/how-to-index-and-search-two-different-tables-which-are-in-same-datasource-using 
This problem can solve by using static field (adding new field - here its **'entity'**). 
But I saw that after adding second entity, it can't even index the data.

As per picture shown below.[image: Multiple entity issue - Template Transformer issue]

Its able to **fetch 10 records** from sql server database but **index 0 rows**, means no indexing process done.
So even can't search.
Anyone can solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any workaround for this question???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the fields in your schema have

```
required="true".
```

You're telling Solr that the results from each entity need to have ALL of the eid, ename, pid, pname, entity, and singlekey fields.

Employee doesn't have a pid or pname field, so pid and pname shouldn't be required. In the same sense, Product doesn't have a eid or ename field, so eid and ename shouldn't be required.

Removing

```
required="true".
```

from pid, pname, eid, and ename will allow you to index.

Comment: Thanks, you are true that's the only root cause for not indexing data. (y)

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried indexing your entities individually from admin screen

```
http://<hostname>:<portnum>/solr
```